# One Dirac fermion built from two real fermions with different velocities?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, conformal-field-theory, fermions

If I have a massless field theory of two decoupled real fermions with different velocities (let's think of 1+1d for simplicity). Is it `allowed' to rescale the arguments of the fields to combine them into one complex fermion, such that the action has a $U(1)$ symmetry? Or is there something preventing me from doing that, meaning this theory does not have a $U(1)$ symmetry?

Answer (score 0):

No, when you scale the fields, you also change the equal time commutators. Thinking of the $1+1$ problem in terms of chiral bosons, whose equal time commutators have the form:
$$\left [\phi_L(x), \phi_L(y) \right ]=   i \pi \mathrm{sign}(x-y)$$
It is obvious that they will be correspondingly scaled also. 
The time evolution is governed by both Hamiltonian and commutators. Only when both are invariant, the theory becomes invariant.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Hm, I was talking about rescaling the *arguments* of the fields, not the fields themselves (concretely: $\phi(x,t) \to \phi(x,\lambda t)$ instead of $\phi(x,t) \to \lambda \; \phi(x,t)$). That would not affect the commutator you mention. However, I presume that you're implying that the type of transformation I am suggesting, would have to be accompanied by a rescaling of the field itself as well? (That would seem plausible...)

Comment: I don't see how scaling the arguments of two identical fields can change the scaling of their Hamiltonians differently. 
By the way, scaling time does change the equal time commutators.